# Upgrade to 12.04 LTS failed, unable to boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, upgrade, mount, boot-failure

I was trying to upgrade to 12.04 LTS, but the upgrade froze in the process (it was stuck for over 8 hours) and I had to do a hard reboot.  Now when I boot up, I get the following:

```
mountall /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 version 'glibc_2.14' not found.
```

I'm not sure what I need to do from here.  Do I need to go back to the previous version?  Or can 12.04 still be installed?  I don't want to lose any of my files.

I am still new to Linux, so please give detailed step-by-step instructions.

Comment: If you happen to have your files on a separate partition to your system one I'd try again. It's situations like this that taught me to keep /home on a separate partition to /

Comment: I can't find an option to try to install the upgrade again.  I have found my files, but I still don't know the best option on how to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Use usb live Ubuntu to live boot to computer. You can use [Unetbootin](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/using-unetbootin-to-create-a-live-usb-linux/) on windows or on Ubuntu using [Startup Disk Creator](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

[How to Create a Bootable Linux USB Drive on Windows](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-on-windows-mac-and-linux)

Boot live Usb in computer where you want to get files from- [Try Ubuntu before you install it](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install)

In booted live usb Ubuntu open file manager and you will see the hard drive of computer. Open home folder and get files.

Add external drive to computer to witch to copy files you need.

Can you get all files like this? Was this helpful?